# Unable to remove red circle with white line

Tags: apt

I recently tried to update Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer, but I am unable to do this because a red circle with a white line at the top of my screen. When I run the update in the terminal, I get this error message:

```
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What to do?

Comment: Could you paste the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` somewhere and give a link in your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities to deal with this issues:

You can either remove the file or move it to another place:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list /var/tmp
```

Now the file lives in `/var/tmp` and you can analyze it if you want.

I guess you wanted the contents like the [download page at playonlinux.com](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) it describes. 
The file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` should contain the following line:

```
deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main
```

So you should edit the file and insert the line above (all other content should be removed). You can also do the following steps to regain the contents:

1. Open a terminal
2. Enter `wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list`
3. Enter `sudo mv playonlinux_precise.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list`

Now you can run `apt-get update` and the error has disappeared.

Comment: Why not edit the file in it's current location to deal with the error.

Comment: That's what I ment with my last sentence. Will edit the question.